# MS SQL BCP: Unable to resolve column level collations

Tags: sql, bcp

I have an issue with BCP which is driving me insane, and despite looking at many other articles I cannot see a resolution.

I have a fairly lengthy stored procedure that I am trying to call from a Windows 10 machine to store into a CSV file. Some work, others do not

Working (Windows 10, BCP version 11.0.2100.60):

```
BCP "exec <db>.dbo.andy" queryout test.csv /S <server-ip> /c /t; /T /v /r 0x0A
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 11.0.2100.60



Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Warning: BCP import with a format file will convert 
empty strings in delimited columns to NULL.

997 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 578    Average : (1724.91 rows per sec.)
```

Not Working (Windows 10, BCP Version 11.0.2270.0):

```
BCP "exec <db>.dbo.andy" queryout test.csv /S <server-ip> /c /t; /T /v /r 0x0A
BCP - Bulk Copy Program for Microsoft SQL Server.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
Version: 11.0.2270.0



Starting copy...
SQLState = 01000, NativeError = 7412
Warning = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]OLE DB provider 
"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "TEMP" returned message "Unspecified error".
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 7303
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot initialize the data source 
object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "TEMP".
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to resolve column level collations

BCP copy out failed
```

The linked server "TEMP" is a linked server point to a CSV file stored locally on the SQL Server (SQL 14.0.3257 running on Windows Server 2016)

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: One obvious difference is `ODBC Driver 11` vs. `ODBC Driver 13`. `bcp` does not come with a driver itself (I think) and we're already up to [version 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server), so I'd first try upgrading that.

Comment: Having said that, the error itself seems to stem from the configuration of the ACE OLEDB driver and not directly related to ODBC (anything's possible, of course, but still). Are you calling on the same server in both instances? If not, a configuration difference there is the most likely explanation.

Comment: Hi both the working and non-working are targeting exactly the same server and store procedure. But I will have a look at the ODBC driver version